# Android RelativeLayout.LayoutParams can not cast to AbsListview.LayoutParams (Error below 4.4.4) Working fine on 5.0 & 6.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I have used a `ListView` and the parent in the `xml` is `RelativeLayout`.
When I run the app on 4.4.4 it gives me `ClassCastException` but when I run it on 5.0.1 or 6.0.1 it runs without any error. Please have a look in the code snippet.

**Error :**

```
09-21 10:39:16.410 14394-14394/com.spicex E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1849)
                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1816)
                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1641)
                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2603)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1666)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1442)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1191)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2376)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2089)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1264)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6632)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Activity
09-21 10:39:16.640 14394-14394/com.spicex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.spicex, PID: 14394
                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
                                                                at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1849)
                                                                at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1816)
                                                                at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
                                                                at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
                                                                at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1641)
                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2603)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1666)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1442)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1191)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15859)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2376)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2089)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1264)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6632)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java
```

**GetView Method:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SpiceXHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new SpiceXHolder();
        convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_spicex_result_screen, parent, false);
        holder.profileImageIV = (RoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileImageIV);
        /*holder.imagePagerVP.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());*/
        holder.userInfoLL = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userInfoLL);
        holder.usernameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTV);
        holder.distanceTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distanceTV);
        holder.availablityTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.availablityTV);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (SpiceXHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    prevPos = position;
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mResultScreenData.get(position).getAdvert()) {
                Fragment fragment = ((MainActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerFL);
                if (fragment instanceof SpicexResultListFragment) {
                    ((SpicexResultListFragment) fragment).getSpiceXDetails((String) getItem(position).getEmail(), position);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (mResultScreenData.get(position).getAdvert()) {
        Logger.e(TAG, position + "");
        holder.userInfoLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Utils.getInstance().dpToPx(mContext, 90));
        int margin = Utils.getInstance().dpToPx(mContext, 5);
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        holder.profileImageIV.setLayoutParams(params);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.profileImageIV.setCornerRadius(0);
        setImageInView(position, holder, mResultScreenData.get(position).getMedia().get(0), false);
        Logger.e(TAG, mResultScreenData.get(position).getMedia().get(0));
    } else {
        Utils.getInstance().getTimeZone();
        holder.profileImageIV.setCornerRadius(20);
        holder.userInfoLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Utils.getInstance().dpToPx(mContext, 260));
        int margin = Utils.getInstance().dpToPx(mContext, 5);
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        holder.profileImageIV.setLayoutParams(params);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

        holder.distanceTV.setText(mResultScreenData.get(position).getDistance());
        String availText = getAvailabilityText(mResultScreenData.get(position).getFree());
        if (availText.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.check_it_out))) {
            holder.availablityTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.red));
        } else if (availText.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.free_today))) {
            holder.availablityTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.green));
        } else if (availText.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.proposal_sent))) {
            holder.availablityTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.blue));
        }
        holder.availablityTV.setText(availText);
        holder.usernameTV.setText(mResultScreenData.get(position).getUserName());
        if (mResultScreenData.get(position).getMedia().size() > 0)
            setImageInView(position, holder, Constants.URL_IMAGE + mResultScreenData.get(position).getMedia().get(0), true);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

**List item XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layer_list_how_it_works"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <com.spicex.utility.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImageIV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layer_list_how_it_works"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userInfoLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layer_list_gradient_profile_corners"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernameTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/samantha_richards"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_date_avail" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/availablityTV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/free_now"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/green" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/distanceIV"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/distanceTV"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_location" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/distanceTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/fourkm"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: everyone is suggesting to edit the code.. Will you please give a solution?

Comment: Edits make your question more readable to get faster solutions actually.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Comment: ListView was extended from AbsListView, maybe using RecyclerView instead of ListView solves these sort of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
holder.profileImageIV.setLayoutParams(params);
convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If you need to modify existing layout params, access them with `getLayoutParams()`, modify it and then call `requestLayout()` to notify that the layout has changed.

So, instead of

```
convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You may try this

```
LayoutParams params = convertView.getLayoutParams();
int margin = Utils.getInstance().dpToPx(mContext, 5);
params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
convertView.requestLayout();
```

Do the same thing for the `ImageView`

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Answer (score 1):

Here you're replacing existing layout params of correct type `AbsListView.LayoutParams` with more generic `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Utils.getInstance().dpToPx(mContext, 260));
```

Check this part. Try to add LayoutParams of `AbsListView.LayoutParams`. Try it and let me know.

If you need to modify existing layout params, access them with `getLayoutParams()`, modify it, and call `requestLayout()` to notify that the layout has changed.

Comment: I have used RelativeLayout in xml as the parent. I have also tried AbsListView.LayoutParams but it gave me exception that AbsListView.LayoutParams can not cast to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams